# gridview dissapears on rowediting, clicking between two functions brings it back with the item expanded

Tags: asp.net, gridview, editing

Not sure if this is an odd one or not, but i have a gridview that dissapears on rowediting,

my steps are > click butUsers > click edit > grid dissapears > click butDev > grid is back > click ButUsers > grid loads with my selected item in editmode.

whats missing from my event?

Thanks

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class equipment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string strMode;
    ParameterCollection pcEquip;

    dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable dtEquipment;
    dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter taEquipment;
    SqlDataSource dsEquipment;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtEquipment = new dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable();
        taEquipment = new dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter();
        dsEquipment = new SqlDataSource();

        smEquipment.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(butUsers);
    }
    protected void butUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidMode.Value = "Users";
        dtEquipment.Clear();
        taEquipment.FillByUsers(dtEquipment);
        gvItems.DataSource = dtEquipment;
        gvItems.DataBind();

        upTable.Update();
    }
    protected void butDevelopment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hidMode.Value = "Users";
        dtEquipment.Clear();
        taEquipment.FillByDev(dtEquipment);
        gvItems.DataSource = dtEquipment;
        gvItems.DataBind();

        upTable.Update();
    }
    protected void gvItems_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void gvItems_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvItems.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gvItems.DataSource = dtEquipment;
        gvItems.DataBind();
        upTable.Update();

    }
}
```

ASPX PAGE

```
<asp:Content ID="cntCenter" ContentPlaceHolderID="CenterContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upTable" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidMode" />
            <grid:TemplateGridView
                EnableTemplateEditing="True"
                runat="server" ID="gvItems" OnRowDataBound="gvItems_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="gvItems_RowEditing"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True" 
                AllowSorting="True" CssClass="table" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px"
                GridLines="None">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID"
                        SortExpression="UserID" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetNo" HeaderText="Asset No" 
                        SortExpression="AssetNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="User Name"
                        SortExpression="Username" />
                </Columns>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <div class="details">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' />
                        <table class="detailsview" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="td_title_align">Asset No:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssetNo" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box" Text='<%# Bind("AssetNo") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="td_title_align">CPU:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPU" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box" Text='<%# Bind("CPU") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="td_title_align">Shipped Date:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShippedDate" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box" Text='<%# Bind("ShippedDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8">
                                    <div class="footer_command">
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" CssClass="command_button" />
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CssClass="command_button" />
                                    </div>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </grid:TemplateGridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to bind once during pageLoad. I think this code block executes on every Postback in your current code, so this might be rebinding your data tables. You can check by placing a break point on pageload in debug mode (This will be called on every postback). This might solve your problem

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostback)
       {
         dtEquipment = new dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable();
        taEquipment = new dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter();
        dsEquipment = new SqlDataSource();
        smEquipment.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(butUsers);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
What I can understand from your code is that you were initializing data tables & table adapters on `pageLoad`. Now after, we have put the initialization code inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` you would get null references because they are not yet initialized (They were initialized on PageLoad event).

> Remember HTTP is stateless

. To save state of these tables on each postback, you can either use Viewstate or Session.

Comment: when I click butUsers I now get

[code]SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [/code]

I think its referring to dtEquipment as when I click butDev  i get the same error but it refers to dtEquipment

Comment: How do i use session or viewstate, can you show me a sample? Thanks